# Python tkinter, missing positional argument error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to develop a simple python tool using Tkinter.I have created 3 files and below is the code. The files are
GUI.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import versionTab
import logclass

class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        parent.title("Tool")
        parent.geometry('695x600+100+100')
        self.frame = Frame(parent,bd=5).grid()
        self.infoLabel = LabelFrame(self.frame,text="Information",height=100,width=100)
        self.version = versionTab.versionTab(self.infoLabel)
        self.infoLabel.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan =2,padx=8,pady=2,sticky = W)

        self.logLabel = LabelFrame(self.frame,height=1000,width=1000)
        self.Log = logclass.debuglog(self.logLabel)
        self.logLabel.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan =2,padx=8,pady=2,sticky = W)

root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.resizable(0,0)
root.mainloop()
```

The next file is versionTab.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import logclass

class versionTab():
    def __init__(self,frame):
        self.firmwareFrame =LabelFrame(frame,height=15,width=100)
        self.firmwareversion_B = Button(self.firmwareFrame, text=" Version",command= self.getFW).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=2,pady=5)
        self.versionText_Entry = Entry(self.firmwareFrame,width=10)
        self.versionText_Entry.configure(state ='readonly')
        self.versionText_Entry.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=4,pady=5)
        self.firmwareFrame.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan =2,padx=2,pady=2,sticky = W)

    def getFW(self):
        logclass.debuglog.logst(self,"12344")
```

final file is logclass.py

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from datetime import datetime

class debuglog():
    def __init__(self,frame):
        self.debuglog = LabelFrame(frame,text = "Log",height=15,width=100)
        self.log      = Text(self.debuglog,height = 20, width = 80)
        self.scrollb  = Scrollbar(self.debuglog, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.scrollb.config(command = self.log.yview) 
        self.log.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollb.set)
        self.log.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.scrollb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=W)
        self.debuglog.pack()

    def logst(self,msg, level=None):
        print('logclass')
        self.log.insert(insert('end', msg + '\n'))

    def exitWindow(self):

        print('exit..')
```

while I are running my GUI.py file I am able to generate the tool.The tool will display a simple button version.when I click the version button on tool its throwing the below error

```
versionTab.py", line 15, in getFW
    logclass.debuglog.logst(self)
TypeError: logst() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
```

Could any one tell me why I am not able to call the logst from my versiontab file

Comment: The line in the error traceback does not match with the posted code for `versionTab.py`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be attempting to call the method `logst` on the class `debuglog`. This will not work, as "logst" is not a static method. You would need to create an instance of `debuglog` in order to call the method `logst` on it.

I also do not understand why you are passing `self` to the `logst` function when you call it

In the constructor for the `versionTab` class, you could add `self._logger = logclass.debuglog()`, and then call `self._logger.logst` rather than `logclass.debuglog.logst`.

Perhaps look into the differences between static methods and non static methods?